# Working Eclipse Cocos2dx android project suddenly giving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

Ok, I did my homework and searched around, but no one seem to be having quite the same problem, but tried solutions to similar problems to no avail.

The peculiarity of my issue is that the project was working just fine last Thursday (last day I messed with it), but when I opened it this Tuesday, it just wouldn't build, giving me the mentioned error.

And no, neither I nor anyone else as much as touched the project nor Eclipse.

Another thing I've noticed is that, even though the project *is* properly converted to C/C++, it somehow at the same time is not, as at the project/properties/Paths and Symbols section Includes/Symbols tabs are missing; similarly, under Tool Chain Editor it simply doesn't show the dropdown option "No ToolChain" anymore (it did before as it was supposed to).

Doesn't seem to be an issue with Eclipse as a whole since I was able to properly convert a different Java project to C/C++ without any issues, but I'm at a loss on what to do now or how to find the real problem.

Anyone happens to know how to "unconvert" a project so I can start the whole thing from scratch without having to manually start a new project?

EDIT: Fixed the project, for the record, it was some insane error that came out of literally nowhere, which caused the Properties to lose reference and add a bunch of filters that disabled both Classes and com.example.myproject.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your libgame.so under the category ProjectHome->libs->armeabi->libgame.so have gone missing.